# Can snapped vertices be automatically merged?

Tags: modeling, snapping

Two vertices snap together when *snapping during transform* is enabled with *snap onto self* :

[image]

[image]

How could both vertices be merged?

Comment: not sure what the question is asking, you want auto-merge to merge both?

Comment: In case anyone else is confused, you might want to also see this [chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/conversation/automerge-confusion)

Comment: I rephrased this, now it should make more sense.

Comment: You can also make point "active element" to make dots untstacked and merged in 1 true dot. (Sometimes it can be turned off)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AutoMerge Editing might be what you are looking for.  It can be toggled on and off by clicking the entry.

[image]

EDIT: I've added the image posted as a comment by username: gandalf3 since he pointed out that there is also toggle button in the header bar which makes this feature easier to access.

[image]

Comment: Also note that there is a toggle for this in the header of the 3D view. [screenshot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18601284#18601284)

Comment: It's on the top-right of the 3D View-port in Blender 2.80.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** for blender 2.8 OSX (in addition to Meetai.com's comment)

`AutoMerge Editing` can be found

- far right above the outliner within dropdown button `Mesh Options`
- properties panel first tab, Mesh Options. (first tab active tool and workspace settings)

[image]

Source: https://blenderartists.org/t/where-is-automatic-vertex-merge-in-2-8/1119468/3