# How to merge vertices in Blender?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I am attempting to create my first 3D character just for practice. Being one of my first 3d models I going through the learning curve needless to say. In doing so I find myself creating many extra vertices. Where we will say 10 vertices on a rounded shape are spaced out on the equator and on the other north pole end of the edges they are very close. The close end could all be one vertex. Is it possible to say merge all points to one point and delete the rest?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18833/1853

Answer (score 65):

There is a merge tool.
Select the vertices you want to merge.
Press <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> (or <kbd>M</kbd> for Blender 2.8)

There are a few options:

At **First**, or **Last** will merge the points depending on the order in which the vertices where selected.

At center. will merge the vertices at the center of all selected vertices.

At cursor will merge the selected vertices where the 3D cursor is.

[image]

I recommend you read **[this page](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html?highlight=merge)** of the blender manual for this and other ways to deal with Deleting and Merging

Comment: For Blender 2.80 and above just press <kbd>M</kbd> instead

Answer (score 15):

You can [automatically merge](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html#automerge-editing) vertices that are very close to each other (within a given distance).

Mode: Edit Mode

Menu: Mesh ‣ AutoMerge Editing

Comment: This literally just saved me an hour's work and 400 strands of hair.

Comment: No problem, I learned it by reading the blender reference manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/index.html Blender has so much power its hard to wrap my head around it.

Comment: 2.8 : there is a "Auto merge" checkbox under the "Options" tab of the "Active Tool" panel.

Comment: There's also a "Merge by Distance" command if you only want to do this once.

Comment: Wow, they did a really good job at hiding everything in Blender 2.8 :)

Answer (score 9):

For Blender 2.83 its just <kbd>M</kbd>  instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>