# How to weld a vertex onto an edge

Tags: modeling, mesh

So I'm making glasses because that's what I decided to make (still learning so making simple objects) and ran into this problem. I have no clue how to put these vertices (I think they're called) onto the edge here. Is there any way to merge, or weld them onto it?[image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36812/how-do-i-snap-one-vertex-to-the-position-of-another-vertex-in-a-different-object/36815#36815. You should look into the snap tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another edge loop in the crossbar piece (the top of the glasses) and move that edge loop near the vertices you are trying to join. So you'll something like this

```
|           |         |
*-----------*---------*
           *-*
           | |
```

Becomes this:

```
|          | |         |
*----------*-*---------*
           *-*
           | |
```

For more on adding loop cuts, [click here](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop_subdivide.html)

Then merge the vertices using Alt+M.

Which becomes this:

```
|          | |         |
*----------*-*---------*
           | |
```

For more on merging : [click here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34038/24480)

Comment: I used this just now but I have to do it 1 by 1 or else it'll distort itself. It still worked so thanks!

Comment: Exactly. Merge each vertex 1 by 1. Glad that helped. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of merging, turn on Snap by clicking this button, or Shift+Tab.
[image]

Then select the face you want to be close to those vertices and when moving, this little orange circle will appear, meaning it snapped to the vertex.[image]