# Merge vertex into an edge

Tags: edges, vertex-groups, knife-tool, 3d-cursor

I'd like to merge a vertex into an edge without subdivide the edge and merge the vertices;

i usually use the knife tool, create a second vertex in the edge, set "cursor to selected" to the first target vertex, and select both the vertices, and merge them with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> *> At cursor*, it works when you have a plane, but it's really slow...

how can i done it automatically or in quickly way?

[image]

Comment: You could use `Alt`+`D` command with vertex selected where you'd like to create one more vertex. There is *At Last* option in the `Alt`+`M` command, so no need to change location of the cursor

Comment: Does this help http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18828/can-snapped-vertices-be-automatically-merged ?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the automerge editing is really useful, but is there a way to create a vertex into the edge without knife tool or a way to merge the vertex into the edge when the vertex is aligned in the edge?