# How to merge a vertex to an edge?

Tags: vertices, edit-mode, edges

I occasionally have two objects with a vertex overlapping an edge:

[image: Edges]

My question is how can you create vertices on the edge touching the other vertices, without having to subdivide and merge. In this situation it would be quite simple, but other times it might be more complicated. Is there an addon that can do this?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42678/merge-vertex-into-an-edge?rq=1

Comment: @360ueck I couldn't get that to work...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case of intersecting meshes *Intersect* operator could be useful. In this case, *Intersect / Knife* is the one needed.

1. Select faces which intersect (or select all faces if convenient).
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> > *Intersect / Knife*. Faces were cut, i.e. one from the rightmost cube got 2 new vertices and became an Ngon. However meshes aren't connected yet, because there are 2 pairs of vertices which share the same location.
3. Remove doubles with <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove doubles*. Now meshes are connected.

   [image: cutting edge of mesh with edge of another mesh GIF]

*Note: Intersect / Knife tool is accessible starting from [version 2.77](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77)*.

Answer (score 3):

Let's call the left cube Cube A and right cube Cube B.

1. With the Knife tool ( <kbd>K</kbd> ) create a vertex in the edge of Cube B you want to create the vertex to merge it (click on it and then press Enter).
2. Merge both cubes (select them both in *Object mode* and <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>.
3. Select the vertex you just created in Cube B and [snap it](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html) (hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to snap after pressing <kbd>G</kbd>, make sure it's on *vertex* mode and not *increment*) to the vertex you want to merge in Cube A.
4. <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove doubles*
5. Get rid of N-gons (you can select the faces with N-gons in Cube B and press <kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd> to triangulate and then <kbd>Alt + J</kbd> to quadrangulate).

Comment: That's honestly a little more complicated than I would like.

Comment: I bet there is no much easier solution... at least no generally applicable one.

Comment: What am I missing?  I can't seem to create a single vertex with the knife tool.  I click it, get the little green dot and then press enter and nothing happens (besides deselecting).  It does work if I link two dots (across a face, for example)...

Answer (score 1):

The new Exact Solver for the *Boolean* modifier will do this if the vertices are on the edge.

[image]